# Using Pulumi and Azure, is there any API to create a SecretProviderClass without using yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, pulumi

I'm trying to find a better way to solve this scenario than resorting to a yaml inside a pulumi.apply call (which has problems with preview apparently).

The idea here is (using Azure Kubernetes) to create a secret and then make it available inside a pod (nginx pod here just for test purposes).

The current code works, but is there an API that I'm missing?
Started to mess around with:

```
   const foobar = new k8s.storage.v1beta1.CSIDriver("testCSI", { ...
```

but not really sure if it is the right path and if it is, what to put where to get the same effect.

*Sidenote, no, I do not want to put secrets into environment variables. Although convenient they leak in the gui and logs and possibly more places.*

```
const provider = new k8s.Provider("provider", {
  kubeconfig: config.kubeconfig,
  namespace: "default",
});

const secret = new keyvault.Secret("mysecret", {
  resourceGroupName: environmentResourceGroupName,
  vaultName: keyVaultName,
  secretName: "just-some-secret",
  properties: {
    value: administratorLogin,
  },
});

pulumi.all([environmentTenantId, keyVaultName, clusterManagedIdentityClientId])
      .apply(([environmentTenantId, keyVaultName, clusterManagedIdentityClientId]) => {
         let yammie = `apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
              kind: SecretProviderClass
              metadata:
                name: azure-kvname-system-msi
              spec:
                provider: azure
                parameters:
                  usePodIdentity: "false"
                  useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
                  userAssignedIdentityID: "${clusterManagedIdentityClientId}"
                  keyvaultName: ${keyVaultName}
                  cloudName: ""                   
                  objects:  |
                    array:
                      - |
                        objectName: just-some-secret
                        objectType: secret        
        
                  tenantId: ${environmentTenantId}`;

  const yamlConfigGroup = new k8s.yaml.ConfigGroup("test-secret",
    {
      yaml: yammie,
    },
    {
      provider: provider,
      dependsOn: [secret],
    }
  );
});

const deployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment(
  name,
  {
    metadata: {
      labels: appLabels,
    },
    spec: {
      replicas: 1,
      selector: { matchLabels: appLabels },
      template: {
        metadata: {
          labels: appLabels,
        },
        spec: {
          containers: [
            {
              name: name,
              image: "nginx:latest",
              ports: [{ name: "http", containerPort: 80 }],
              volumeMounts: [
                {
                  name: "secrets-store01-inline",
                  mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store",
                  readOnly: true,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
          volumes: [
            {
              name: "secrets-store01-inline",
              csi: {
                driver: "secrets-store.csi.k8s.io",
                readOnly: true,
                volumeAttributes: { secretProviderClass: "azure-kvname-system-msi" },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    provider: provider,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SecretsProviderClass` is a [CustomResource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) which isn't typed because the fields can be anything you want.

```js
const secret = new k8s.apiextensions.CustomResource("cert", {
    apiVersion: "secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1",
    kind: "SecretProviderClass",
    metadata: {
        namespace: "kube-system",
    },
    spec: {
        provider: "azure",
        secretObjects: [{
            data: [{
                objectName: cert.certificate.name,
                key: "tls.key",
            }, {
                objectName: cert.certificate.name,
                key: "tls.crt"
            }],
            secretName: "ingress-tls-csi",
            type: "kubernetes.io/tls",
        }],
        parameters: {
            usePodIdentity: "true",
            keyvaultName: cert.keyvault.name,
            objects: pulumi.interpolate`array:\n  - |\n    objectName: ${cert.certificate.name}\n    objectType: secret\n`,
            tenantId: current.then(config => config.tenantId),
        }
    }
}, { provider: k8sCluster.k8sProvider })
```

Note: the objects array might work with `JSON.stringify`, but I haven't yet tried that.

If you want to get strong typing for a card, you can use [crd2pulumi](https://github.com/pulumi/crd2pulumi)

Comment: There is a full implemenation of this using Azure classic located here: https://github.com/jaxxstorm/pulumi-examples/blob/main/typescript/azure/aks_aad_nginx/aksidentity.ts

Comment: Looks very promising! Will try to fit it into my solution later this week. Thanks!